# I got error with undefined variable when to display

Tags: angular, typescript

I got error `Error: _co.bellowContent is undefined`  when to display data. You can refer my code bellow.
I got error `Error: _co.bellowContent is undefined`  when to display data. You can refer my code bellow.

app.component.html

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let tableRow of table" (click)="open(tableRow)">
      <th scope="row">{{tableRow.id}}</th>
      <td>{{tableRow.first}}</td>
      <td>{{tableRow.last}}</td>
      <td>{{tableRow.title}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div>
<p>id: {{ bellowContent.id }}</p>
<p>first: {{ bellowContent.first }}</p>
<p>last: {{ bellowContent.last }}</p>
<p>title: {{ bellowContent.title }}</p>
</div>
```

And

app.component.ts

```
  bellowContent:undefined
  table = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first":"Robin",
    "last": "William",
    "title": "back end developer"
  },{
    "id": 2,
    "first":"Mark",
    "last": "Thornton",
    "title": "front end developer"
  },{
    "id": 3,
    "first":"Tary",
    "last": "Huction",
    "title": "front end developer"
  }
]


  open(tableRow) {
      this.bellowContent = tableRow
  }
}
```

This is my code in [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nhoazu)

Comment: dude why you are removing answer?

Comment: no... I'm not removed answer..

Comment: now it is in position maked or removed

Comment: ok.. I marked back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are defining it as undefined, it will be undefined in the first place, inorder to handle the undefined error. Use Safe Navigation operator as follows,

```
<p>id: {{ bellowContent?.id }}</p>
<p>first: {{ bellowContent?.first }}</p>
<p>first: {{ bellowContent?.last }}</p>
<p>first: {{ bellowContent?.title }}</p>
```

Also proper way to initialize the bellowContent as an Empty object

```
 bellowContent = {};
```

[`STACKBLITZ DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nvsfxi?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `bellowContent` to an empty object `{}` rather than `undefined`:

```
bellowContent = {};
```

---

On further study of your code, it seems that it may not be desirable to display the labels id, first,etc until and unless the user clicks on one of the rows. In that case, you can just wrap the content you want to display using

```
<div *ngIf="bellowContent">
   ...
</div>
```

and keep your initial *initialization* of bellowContent to `bellowContent:undefined`

Comment: I removed my downvote but this is still a dirty hack. undefined is the correct value for no selection made and the div should be hidden with an ngIf. An empty object is a hack.

Answer (score 1):

Dont't keep undefined as type, put *ngIf condition to the div

Modified code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zftsyc?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1):

Use an ngIf on the content trying to access properties on an undefined object. It looks cleaner than having the safe navigation operator everywhere.

```
<div *ngIf="bellowContent">
<p>id: {{ bellowContent.id }}</p>
<p>first: {{ bellowContent.first }}</p>
<p>last: {{ bellowContent.last }}</p>
<p>title: {{ bellowContent.title }}</p>
</div>
```